# PHP не понятное поведение array unshift / array filter

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, мне нужно удалить пустые элементы массива, и добавить один элемент в начало. Я могу сделать это так:

```
$users = array_filter($users);
array_unshift($users, 'userid');
```

Но я привык сокращать код, по этому пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
array_unshift(array_filter($users), 'userid');
```

Но тогда почему то массив получается вовсе пустым. Почему? Ведь интерпретатор по идее должен вначале очистить пустые элементы при помощи array_filter, а потом уже в пустой массив добавлять значение в его начало.

Answer (score 1):

> *Но тогда почему то массив получается вовсе пустым. Почему?*

Потому что функция array_unshift() принимает значение переменной по ссылке **&**:

```
int array_unshift ( array &$array , mixed $value1 [, mixed $... ] )
```

Сохраняйте массив в переменную, и передавайте на вход эту переменную, а не результат вычисления какого либо выражения. Такое поведение касается всех php-функций, принимающих параметры по ссылке.